# How to wrap function with void* parameter, %typemap

Tags: c#, c++, api, swig

I got to extend the wrapping of a C++ API (Cinema 4D SDK for my thesis project) which was wrapped to c# with SWIG 3.0 by a student team. I cannot change any of the API code.

For now, I'm struggling at wrapping a specific function. The function is defined like this in the C++ `c4d_nodedata.h` file:

```
virtual Bool Message(GeListNode* node, Int32 type, void* data);
```

If I'm not doing anything specific in my SWIG `.I` file the function is wrapped to this:

```
public virtual bool Message(GeListNode node, int type, SWIGTYPE_p_void data) {
    bool ret = C4dApiPINVOKE.NodeData_Message(swigCPtr, GeListNode.getCPtr(node), type, SWIGTYPE_p_void.getCPtr(data));
    return ret;
}
```

This function is part of a messaging system in the API and for the parameter `data` a specific object is given with a call which is of the type `DocumentInfoData`:

```
public override bool Message(GeListNode node, int type, SWIGTYPE_p_void data)
```

So in C++ it's a basic void pointer I could cast, whatever, to my `DocumentInfoData` type object and then work on this. In C# I cannot cast this as all methods in `SWIGTYPE_p_void` are either private or internal by standard - so there are no getters etc.

I now tried to wrap this with a `%typemap` in swig. The `%typemap` looks like this:

```
%typemap(ctype) void*, void*& "void* /* void* */" 
%typemap(in) void*  %{ $1 = (void*)$input; /* void*_in */%} 
%typemap(in) void*& %{ $1 = (void**)&$input;  /* void*&_in */%} 
%typemap(imtype, out="global::System.IntPtr") void*, void*& "DocumentInfoData /* DocumentInfoData_imtype */" 
%typemap(cstype, out="global::System.IntPtr") void*, void*& "DocumentInfoData /* DocumentInfoData_cstype */" 
%typemap(csin) void*, void*& "$csinput /* DocumentInfo_csin */"
```

This wraps the parameter value to the correct `DocumentInfoData` type. But I'm getting errors for other methods which `%typemaps` etc. are overwritten by my `%typemap` and which for example don't normally cast `void*` to `DocumentInfoData` but rather do something different.

Is there a way to only use such SWIG `%typemaps` on some specific function? I know about the scope part in SWIG doc. but it seems to work only with inline code.

I am also aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25310530) question, but it has not been answered with a suitable answer.

Comment: I used a workaround to fix this problem due to the time pressure i got. We created a c++ class deriving from the base class and re-implemented the Message function to accept the already casted parameter. So we are re-implementing a lot in c++ because swig can handle it a lot easier. I can give more details on this if someone requieres.

Comment: Please answer your own question with added details as I'd like to know  how you solved this.  Thanks.